# Bitcore won't install

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, bitcore

I have been trying to install bitcore using npm version 3.8.7 but keep getting the following error:

any help would be much appreciated

> npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "bitcore" "-g" "--save" 
>   npm ERR! node v5.6.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
>   npm ERR! code 128
>   npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/apprentice/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git@github.com:bitpay/engine.io-client.git /Users/apprentice/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-bitpay-engine-io-client-git-bitpay-1-5-4-534e88e8
>   npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/apprentice/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-bitpay-engine-io-client-git-bitpay-1-5-4-534e88e8'...
>   npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.121' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>   npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
>   npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   npm ERR! and the repository exists.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/apprentice/Desktop/BitReturn/npm-debug.log

Comment: I can see "-g", I hope you are using sudo permissions...... "sudo npm install bitcore -g --save" should do...